# Existe alguma forma de forçar prefers-color-scheme?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo web que irá adaptar as cores para o que o usuário preferir. Pretendo criar uma opção para forçar tema claro e uma para forçar tema escuro. Atualmente tenho um código que altera as cores com base no que está configurado no sistema operacional.

Para ambos estilos claros e escuros eu já tenho as definições CSS. Todos os elementos estão usando as cores definidas em `:root`.

Já funciona muito bem com o modo automático, no entanto, gostaria de criar uma opção para o usuário escolher uma opção que sobrescreva o que foi configurado no sistema/navegador.

No meu CSS eu tenho algo parecido com isso:

```css
:root {
    --bg: white;
    --fr: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --bg: black;
        --fr: white;
    }
}
```

Este seletor `@media` é automático com base no que está configurado no sistema operacional. Existe alguma forma de forçar o valor de `prefers-color-scheme`, sobrescrevendo as configurações do sistema operacional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe alguma forma de manipular `prefers-color-scheme`. Essa propriedade é controlada pelo navegador, que normalmente é configurada por uma configuração específica ou pelo sistema operacional.

No entanto, é possível observar quando essa *media-query* é alterada, e então, usar classes para manipular os resultados.

O seletor `:root` é equivalente ao `html`, pois ele seleciona o elemento raiz da página, ou seja, sempre a tag `<html>`.

Contudo, podemos modificar nosso CSS para:

```css
html {
    --bg: white;
    --fr: black;
}

html.dark-mode {
    --bg: black;
    --fr: white;
}

body {
    color:            var(--fr);
    background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

As variáveis continuarão sendo acessíveis ao decorrer de toda a aplicação.

Com a classe `dark-mode` no HTML, a aplicação ficará no tema escuro. Podemos vincular ela ao `prefers-color-scheme` com Javascript:

```js
const darkModePreference = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
darkModePreference.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.matches) {
        document.querySelector("html").classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
        document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
});
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621784/how-to-detect-prefers-color-scheme-change-in-javascript) do código acima.

O código acima irá monitorar sempre que `prefers-color-scheme` for alterado. Quando for alterado e estiver "ativado", `<html>` receberá a classe `dark-mode`.

Para ajustar ao meu problema, fiz uma condição para quando quero que o tema fique claro, escuro ou automático:

```js
window.preferedColorSchemeClassName = "";

const darkModePreference = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
darkModePreference.addEventListener("change", determinePreferedColor);

function changeTheme(t) {
    switch (t) {
        case "dark":
            document.querySelector("html").className = "dark-mode";
            break;
        case "light":
            document.querySelector("html").className = "";
            break;
        case "auto":
            document.querySelector("html").className = window.preferedColorSchemeClassName;
            break;
    }
}

function determinePreferedColor(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        window.preferedColorSchemeClassName = "dark-mode";
    } else {
        window.preferedColorSchemeClassName = "";
    }
    changeTheme("auto");
}

determinePreferedColor(darkModePreference);
```

```css
html {
  --bg: white;
  --fr: black;
}

html.dark-mode {
  --bg: black;
  --fr: white;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: var(--fr);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
  <p>Experimente alterar as cores do seu sistema</p>
  <button onclick="changeTheme('dark')">Usar tema escuro</button>
  <button onclick="changeTheme('light')">Usar tema claro</button>
  <button onclick="changeTheme('auto')">Usar tema automático</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Dessa forma, posso optar em usar o tema escuro, claro ou deixar o sistema operacional decidir.